How to load rdb files to local redis server?
Problem Statement: On my local I have downloaded the rdb files from s3 bucket, now i want to load this in my local redis-server.
I am running following commands

mv /Users/myUser/Downloads/dump.rdb /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb
sudo chown $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb
ls -lh /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb Output for this is : -rw-rw----@ 1 myUser  staff   843M Apr 26 20:29 /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb
brew services restart redis
ls -lh /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb Output for this is : -rw-rw----@ 1 myUser  staff   155B Apr 26 20:29 /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis/dump.rdb
redis-cli
keys *

but when i do keys * , data is not getting loaded into my local redis
what i am missing here ?
